# Using INSERT INTO.....SELECT for importing Excel to Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to import data from Excel to Access.

The Excel file gets selected using

```
Function selectFile()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        If .Show Then
            selectFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            End
        End If
    End With

    Set fd = Nothing
End Function
```

The file selected will always have just 1 worksheet

Up to now I have been using TransferSpreadsheet

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "Summary", selectFile(), True
```

and all was well. However, the selected file may have additional, unwanted, columns of data. I just need the data in the first columns of data, Row 1 is a header row and the headers in the excel sheet match the first 4 column headers in the Access "Summary" Table ("OFFER", "DESCRIPTION", "Total AMRM", "RMACCNUM").

An additional problem is that the worksheet with the data can be named "Sheet1", "Summary", or maybe something else!

I have tried INSERT INTO......SELECT....FROM but cannot get the syntax right.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert into Access Select from Excel from within Access VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896746/insert-into-access-select-from-excel-from-within-access-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a temp location for mapping (and filtering) issues, gives you better control over the process

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "TempSummary", selectFile(), True
```

Then Check Mappings, and insert the data:

```
CurrentDB.Execute "INSERT INTO Summary (OFFER, DESCRIPTION, [Total AMRM], RMACCNUM) " & _   
"SELECT(OFFER, DESCRIPTION, [Total AMRM], RMACCNUM) " & _   
"FROM TempSummary"
```

Finaly, delete the Temp table:

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete "TempSummary"
```

Comment: Had to remove the parentheses after SELECT, but otherwise perfect solution, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will be better off *linking* the spreadsheet.

Then create a simple *select query* that uses the linked table as source. In this, rename (alias) the fields if needed, and do simple converting and filtering like converting text data to numbers, text dates to true dates, excluding Null values, etc.

Save this query and use it for your further processing like appending records to existing tables.